# CSS - img with display block and a href

Tags: html, css, image

I use an `img` with `display: block;` in order to display them one below the other and the second one refers to a link. This works fine except for the fact when I mouse over the second image it refers to the link even the right white space. How can I fix this?

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

and

```
<img src="smiley.gif">
<a href="www.google.com">
    <img src="smiley.gif">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stack your images one above the other I suggest you avoid using `<br>` tags as other answers propose and instead use a clean CSS solution such as flexbox's `flex-direction` property.

**Code**:

```css
.parent {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.parent {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

img {
   max-width: 5em;
   max-height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent">
  <img src = "//www.clker.com/cliparts/3/m/v/Y/E/V/small-red-apple-hi.png"/>
  <a href = "//openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg">
    <img src = "//openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<br />` element to make it appear on a new line, instead of `display: block`.

Comment: Why would one do this instead of using block level display?

Comment: Because it isn't a block level element. Block level elements do not simply mean "line break before this element." They have other side-effects, one of which is what is causing OP's issue. If they want a line break before the element, there is a line break element that does precisely that.

Comment: Adding a line break does not solve this issue. Try it for yourself

Comment: My suggestion is to use `<br />` _instead of_ `display: block`. Removing the `display: block` is what solves the author's issue. Adding the `<br />` is simply to maintain the line break.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put them into `div` tags, which are block elements and therefore will span the whole width. The images however (being inline elements) *won't* spread across the whole width of the DIVs, so you won't have the unwanted hover effect you describe:

```css
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/fa0">
</div>
<div>
  <a href="www.google.com">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150/f0a">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

just do this

```
<img src="smiley.gif"><br>
<a href="www.google.com">
    <img src="smiley.gif">
</a>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.